# Null pointer exception while declaring and initializing Sprite array andengine

Tags: java, arrays, sprite, andengine

I have declared the sprite arrray at the top as:

```
private Sprite[] how_to=new Sprite[4];
```

In createscene method the sprite are initialized as:

```
    how_to[0]=new Sprite(0, 0, resource_manager.how_to_bg_region1, vbx);
    how_to[1]=new Sprite(0, 0, resource_manager.how_to_bg_region2, vbx);
    how_to[2]=new Sprite(0, 0, resource_manager.how_to_bg_region3, vbx);
    how_to[3]=new Sprite(0, 0, resource_manager.how_to_bg_region4, vbx);
    how_to[4]=new Sprite(0, 0, resource_manager.how_to_bg_region5, vbx);
```

Gives null pointer exception:

```
07-10 16:39:27.135: E/AndroidRuntime(778): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
07-10 16:39:27.135: E/AndroidRuntime(778): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 16:39:27.135: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at com.example.cotr.How_to.createScene(How_to.java:27)
```

Comment: how_to[0]=new Sprite(0, 0, resource_manager.how_to_bg_region1, vbx);

Comment: By the way regions are appropriately initialized.

Comment: Check if resource_manager is somehow null.

Comment: Please accept the answer if your problem is solved. Or comment for any workaround required. Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to initialize a Sprite array in createScene method..So the workaround was to create a single sprite in the createScene method and then initialize the other Sprite arrays on onSceneTouchEvent listener.

Answer (score 2):

Your array size is 4. So you can initialize 4 objects starting with the index 0 to 3.

If you want to do this,  `how_to[4]=new Sprite(0, 0, resource_manager.how_to_bg_region5, vbx);` try to increase your array size to 5.

```
private Sprite[] how_to=new Sprite[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized an array of 4 elements and you assign to it 5 elements. Remove the last Sprite

```
how_to[4]=new Sprite(0, 0, resource_manager.how_to_bg_region5, vbx);
```

Comment: He would have also got ArreyIndexOutOfBounds exception had he not got null pointer at line 27. However, this line is not the cause of NPE.

Comment: Even after changing the sprite array size to 5 the same exception is occuring at the line:
how_to[0]=new Sprite(0, 0,resource_manager.how_to_bg_region1, vbx);

Comment: Yes  Kalyan Chavali you are right. So maybe the resource_manager or vbx is not initialized.

Comment: Strange thing:
Sprite h=new Sprite(280, 160, resource_manager.how_to_bg_region1, vbx);  attachChild(h);
Gives me the image